# I shall come, not will

Tags: will-shall

Native speakers, how can you comment such a sentence:

***I shall come, not will***

Can I use it for

***I will definitely come, not maybe***

---

### Adding some information other people asked me about.

How I came to such a question.

Here
[Shall and Will Usage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/202818/shall-and-will-usage/202821?noredirect=1#comment393084_202821)

I asked about ***"Shall I win?"*** pointing that it could have some variants of understanding:

***1) Shall I win? = Should I win?*** (suggestion)

***2) Shall I win? = Will I win?*** (archaic with 1st person)

***3) Shall I win? = is it 100% that I will win?*** (predestination\inevitability)

The excellent guy Mixolydian said either variant was possible, that it didn't matter what person you used **"shall"** with, it could have this **"predestination\inevitability"** anyway. Out of this we're getting that nowadays we can use **"will"** for simple future actions and **"shall"** for almost predicted (almost 100% surety of happening) future actions.

If I want to say to someone:

***Don't be afraid, I will come anyway.***

***Don't get panicked, I will definitely come***

***Be sure, I will come in any case***

I can use **"shall"** for it meanining an action into which I will put 100% effort:

***I shall come!***

And what if my original sentence is

***Don't doubt, I will definitely come, not maybe or probably***

Can I use

***I shall come, not will***

pointing that **"shall"** guarantees me putting all my strengths into it while **"will"** doesn't give any assuarance that I will do everything to finally come.

As I understood, it wasn't very easy to ask such a question because English was different everywhere - US, UK, Australie, Ireland etc. I heard it was acceptabse to use even "thee\thou" in Ireland or somewhere like that while all other world has already forgotten such words...

P.S. What I got from the answers ias that it was better to forget about the existence of **"shall"** cause it created so many misunderstandings:D

Comment: @KentaroTomono Well, first of all, there really is no "question" in this question. OP has particularly asked [or made a statement to] native speakers *"how can you comment such a sentence:"* - note the use of colon as opposed to a question mark. Second, is OP looking for answers or *comments*? Third, it is not clear what OP means by this - ***"I shall come, not will"*** - or this - ***"I will definitely come, not maybe"***. Is OP asking "Can we use *shall* and not *will* in *"I shall come"*? OP's statement does not sound like that.

Comment: @KentaroTomono Fourth, OP has not shared with us what research they have done to solve their problem. If you see the posted reason to why this was put on hold, you will see that it says *"Please edit to add the research you have done in your efforts to answer the question ..."*. It is reasonable to expect that an "asker" first search google, ELL, or EL&U for similar queries and try to solve their problem (i.e., learn themselves). OP has not mentioned if they have at all made any efforts.

Comment: I would also add that there's no background information on where the OP found the sentence is question. A little context is needed to understand if there might be a question lurking beneath the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably to a native

> I **will** come

sounds more definite than

> I **shall** come

Depending on the overall context you could convey a similar idea with an English colloquialism
"No ifs or buts about it" - My answer is not conditional

> Speaker 1: If you're free you should come along, but don't worry about it too much
>
> Speaker 2: No ifs or buts about it! I **shall/will** come

**Shall** sounds more "posh", "fancy" or "upper class," whereas **will** is much more common in regular speech.

Comment: Yeah, I know "shall" is kind of aristocratic.  But here https://www.englishpage.com/modals/shall.html it's said about the inevitability. So, "shall" is 1) just posh 2) just for a bigger guarantee 3) can be both?

Comment: Depends where you are. For me _I shall_ is normal (well, _I'll_ is normal, but...). I would be unlikely to say _I will_ unless I am strongly emphasising the _will_. I'm English.

Answer (score 0):

SHALL with I and We, and WILL with You and the remaining subjects is the usual future tense.  However, the exact reverse is used (WILL with I and We, and SHALL with You and the remaining subjects) when more surety is attached to the sense. According to my professor, the first is ordinary future, and the second, coloured future.

Comment: You want to say "I shall come" - standard,  "I will come" - more surety, "You will come" - standard, "You shall come" - more surety. This way? It still works or it's how it worked at Shakespeare's times?

Answer (score -1):

> **I shall come**
>
> **I will come**
>
> **I shall come, not will**

I think native speakers do not say  that **I will come, not shall**or **I shall come , not will.**

They will say:

> **I will come**

or

> **I shall come**

In fact , There is no difference between the usage of **shall** and **will** in the modern English usage especially with the first person though the purists say that**I shall come is more emphatic and formal than I will come.**.In modern English will is replacing  shall in all tenses especially with the first person. shall is preferred  by the purists for second and third person for obligations and in questions  and  for suggestions with first person.

However, the distinction between shall and will is followed in Great Britain  even now. They say:

> **Shall I open the door?**

but not

> **Will I open the door?**

Here is the link which shows the use of  **will and shall**

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/british-grammar/future-will-and-shall

Comment: But "shall" gives some inevitability while "will" doesn't, no?

Comment: It is said that the practice in Scotland differs from that in England. So, the Scotsman who got into difficulties in the sea off the English coast, and shouted "Nobody shall save me, and I will drown!" did indeed drown because the English who heard him thought it was a statement of intent. In practice, however, in spoken English everyone says "I'll come", so @Englishmonger is right to point out that there is no difference in usage, these days.

Comment: **NO!** It depends where you are. As @JeremyC says, most people say "I'll come". But if I (from England) say "I will come" I mean "I am making a commitment to come", as against "I shall come" which is neutral. Even more in the interrogative: "Shall I open the window?" is normal for me. If I said "Will I open the window?", I am asking somebody to predict. For Scottish people I know, though "WIll I open the window?" is normal.

Comment: Blank spaces come after a comma, but not before. And "in fact" is not one word.

Comment: No.He was drowned.Because they understood  that he wanted to commit suicide.

Comment: Not helped but the could not do anything becuse  he was repeatedly saying  shall, shall.

Comment: For the British Yes.But for the scot  it meant different.